# failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () while adding google+ comments to my web site

Tags: javascript, comments, google-plus

here is the link with code. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lzzs.png)
https://dogemap.com/comments.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi expedita
      quod excepturi, nostrum laudantium nihil, voluptate placeat sed aspernatur
      quisquam sunt accusantium debitis mollitia quibusdam hic, eveniet quidem
      voluptates corrupti.
    </p>
    <hr />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <div id="comments"></div>
    <script>
      console.log("web page url:" + window.location);
      gapi.comments.render("comments", {
        href: window.location,
        width: "624",
        first_party_property: "BLOGGER",
        view_type: "FILTERED_POSTMOD"
      });
    </script>

    <hr />
  </body>
</html>
```

showing below error with following link

https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdogemap.com%2Fcomments.html&width=624&first_party_property=BLOGGER&view_type=FILTERED_POSTMOD&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdogemap.com&search=&hash=&gsrc=3p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.NiyWKb0spSU.O%2Fam%3DwQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMXphmaCtjiU8wyjr_fEsh11HPRog%2Fm%3D__features__#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Cscroll%2Copenwindow&id=I0_1552235795048&_gfid=I0_1552235795048&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fdogemap.com&pfname=&rpctoken=30025092

Comment: Yep...the URL points to a resource that doesn't exist. Is there a question you have?

Comment: Please be more specific. What's the question? What's the desired behavior? What prevented you from accomplishing the desired results? For more information take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your chances of being answered.

Comment: to add google comments to any website, that's the only code I can find. what is wrong with the code in script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plus APIs, including the unsupported ones to add comments to a website, have been discontinued with no replacement.

You can't add "Google+ Comments" to a website.